# refresh token with google api client php

Tags: php, google-api

My pain with google api continues...

I'm able to use a script to use a refresh token - automatically refresh and keep my access to a calender alive. I can interact with the calendar and all is good.

I now want to move on to using the google api client for php and I had this working yesterday whilst my token was valid but now this has expired I can't work out how to use the refresh token to get a new token and to keep authenticating once it expires in the future.

I've found a number of references and tried these - here's my test script so far based on the simple.php example:

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApplicationName("Downs Golfmanager");


// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('XXXXXX');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXX');
$client->refreshToken('X/XXXXX');


$client->setUseObjects(true);
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    /
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
    //$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    $event = new Google_Event();

    $event->setSummary('Appointment');
    $event->setLocation('Somewhere');

    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2013-08-28T14:00:00.000+01:00');
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2013-08-28T15:25:00.000+01:00');
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com', $event);

    //echo "<pre>" . print_r($createdEvent, true) . "</pre>";
    echo $createdEvent->getId();


    //test pulling events
    $events = $cal->events->listEvents('XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com');

    while(true) {
      foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
      }
      $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array(
            'pageToken' => $pageToken,
            'timeMin'=>'2013-08-26T00:00:00+01:00',
            'timeMax'=>'2013-08-31T00:00:00+01:00'
            );
        $events = $cal->events->listEvents('XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com', $optParams);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    //print "<h1>Events List</h1><pre>" . print_r($events, true) . "</pre>";



  $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
  print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";


$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

As with my previous posts I'm not clear what should be going on here. My token has expired - I have the refresh token. what changes to my code do I need to automatically refresh authorisation each time I access.

Edit: The error code is: `The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available`

I've commented out a couple of additional lines above which I'd included in my attempts to solve just to try and avoid confusing further

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK - Based on a couple of posts I've fixed the problem of getting the refresh token to get a new access token. I used this code before I started to attempt any access:

```
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
    $client->refreshToken('X/XXXXXX');
}
```

Where the blanked out part in `refreshToken` is my refresh token. I hard coded the key into the code.

This is probably not the correct solution as I've seen references to storing the key in a database, so presumably I could store the current access token in a db with the refresh token and pull these form the db as and when required to save hard coding them?

Hopefully this method I've used will work again after it expires - fingers crossed!

Comment: do you know of a way I can force an access token to expire so I can test requesting a new access token with a refresh token?

Comment: I think (but not 100%) they only have a short timescale anyway 3600ms? I tested the refresh by sleeoing on it :) I think from menmory you can specify the life of the token in the parameters in the call you make. I found alot of useful info from playing with the oauth playground

Comment: thanks I got it figured out, I got confused when it expired and I was still getting data, my code didn't have a condition to check if the access token expired, or to get a new one using the refresh token. Your code helped, I got it working.

Comment: This is slightly old answer, but since I found it through google search, I figured I would mention that you can retrieve and store the refresh token after signing in through the validation process of the access token, which can be pulled back out into the refresh token request. Also, you can force an access token 'to expire' by the revoke process found in the SDK or revoking access through the service itself.