# Google+: Get access_token for already authorized accounts through PHP client library

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-signin

I am implementing the hybrid sign in flow got login with Google+. What I want to achieve is this:

**One a user has authorized the app, the next time he comes back on the website, I want to log him in automatically.**

In hybrid flow, google automatically logs the user in and displays a welcome back message (javascript sdk) along with returning access token. But this process requries one ajax call to be sent to gogole api.

I want to make this call through the backend itself using Google's PHP client library. Since the app has been authorized already, it should simply return the access token as it does when using javascript sdk. But I am not able to figure out how to achieve this using client library. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In your call parameters set `access_type: 'offline'`, then need to get a new token using the `refresh_token` that is provided **ONCE** at the **FIRST** time of authorisation. You will have to store that `refresh_token` somewhere in your database and pair it up with the user's already expired access token ID or somehow and make another call for a valid access token.

For the time being you can set `approval_prompt: 'force'` but that's merely a development trick not a real solution.

More is explained here [refresh token with google api client php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461143/refresh-token-with-google-api-client-php)

Comment: This I have successfully achieved using JS and PHP client library. What I am not able to achieve is this:

Set `approval_prompt = 'auto'` or `immediate = true` and then do $client->getAccessToken() which should ideally return the access token if app is already authorized or return an error otherwise.

Comment: It won't work like that. Read answer in the link above. You need to `if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) $client->refreshToken($refresh_token_from_db);`

Comment: So does that mean I cannot log a user in automatically, after he has authorized my app **without a redirect or without showing him a prompt if he is already logged into google?** My entire aim to log him in invisibly after the app has been authorized.

Comment: Well, of course you can. Store that auth token into the user's session and log them into your system. If all is right they should not need to re-auth the token, since your site already accepts them as logged in, no?

Comment: So, once the user has closed his browser, sessions values get erased. Next time he comes back, when he clicks on login with google button, he gets a prompt, which flashes for a second and disappears as he had authorized the app well before. This is the bottleneck here. I get your point, but I can't seem to find a way to move this particular to backend without any redirects.

Comment: Well, you can use a cookie or localStorage if you want to. Otherwise there is no prompt box required. You see, `gapi.signin.render('myButton', additionalParams);` already calls the API and if you make a quick AJAX to set the session the user won't even know :)

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing right now. :) But when on homepage, it triggers an automatic redirect which is just odd. On rest of the pages, it works well.